# How to convert a list of edges to a tree in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, tree, binary-tree

I am having a list of edges that has the following format:

```
edges=[[1,4],[1,3],[1,2],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7]]
```

Here in each edge the first element is the parent node and the second is a child node i.e, in

> [1,4]---->(1 is the parent node and 4 is child node)

I have to create a function that returns the pointer to the root of the tree. At first I tried creating a dictionary but after creating I am unable to proceed.

Please provide any ideas of how to implement this?

Comment: Add whatever approach you've come up with

Comment: *" pointer to the root"*: Python has no pointers, just objects.

Comment: "pointer to the root of the tree" --> If a graph is a tree in the graph-theory definition of the term, then **any** node can be used as the root to turn that graph into a tree in the data-structure sense of the term.

Comment: Oops, dismiss my previous comment. What you have is not an (undirected) graph but a directed graph. In the case of directed graph we sometimes like to say "arcs" instead of "edges" to make it explicit that they are directed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to create a tree data structure... moreover Python does not have a pointer data type, so the root of a tree would be an object.

Here is one way to do it:

First define a Node class:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
```

Then the main algorithm:

```
def create_tree(edges):
    # Get all the unique keys into a set
    node_keys = set(key for keys in edges for key in keys)
    # Create a Node instance for each of them, keyed by their key in a dict:
    nodes = { key: Node(key) for key in node_keys }
    # Populate the children attributes from the edges
    for parent, child in edges:
        nodes[parent].children.append(nodes[child])
        # Remove the child from the set, so we will be left over with the root
        node_keys.remove(child)
    # Get the root from the set, which at this point should only have one member
    for root_key in node_keys:  # Just need one
        return nodes[root_key]
```

Run it as follows:

```
# Example run
edges = [[1,4],[1,3],[1,2],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7]]
root = create_tree(edges)
```

If you want to quickly verify the tree's shape, add this method to the `Node` class:

```
    def __repr__(self, indent=""):
        return (indent + repr(self.data) + "\n"
                + "".join(child.__repr__(indent+"  ") 
                          for child in self.children))
```

And use it to print the tree:

```
print(root)
```

This `print` method is just a very simple way to visualise the tree. With a bit more code you can also draw the branches of the tree, but this is enough to debug the code.

Comment: `print()` should be replaced by `__repr__` imo

Comment: @AbhinavMathur, yes, converted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is always a tree (and thus we have no two separate graphs) the task is the as determining which number never appears in the second position.

So:

1. Get a list of all numbers (nodes) which we call `possible_roots`
2. Iterate the list of your edges and remove the child node from our above list `possible_roots`
3. If it is a tree, there must only be one element left in `possible_roots`. This is the root of your tree.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which vertex has no parent. This can be done by building a `set` of all vertices, then discarding vertices that have a parent.

Alternatively, this can be done from building on the one hand, the set of all parent vertices, and on the other hand, the set of all child vertices; then taking the set different `parents - children`.

Then there are three possibilities:

- There are no vertices left. This means that your directed graph contained a cycle, and there is no root. Example: `[[0,1], [1,2], [2,0]]`.
- There is more than one vertex left. This means that your directed graph contains more than one "root". Example: `[[0,2], [1,2]]`.
- There is exactly one vertex left. This must be the root.

```py
# FIRST METHOD
def get_root(dag):
    candidates = set(parent for (parent,_) in dag)
    for _,child in dag:
        candidates.discard(child)
    assert(len(candidates) == 1) # or handle len(candidates) == 0 and len(candidates) > 1 with an if/elif/else
    return candidates.pop()

# SECOND METHOD
def get_root(dag):
    parents, children = map(frozenset, zip(*dag))
    candidates = parents - children
    root, = candidates  # will raise exception if len(candidates) != 1
    return root
```

Testing:

```py
print( get_root([[1,4],[1,3],[1,2],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7]]) )
# 1

print( get_root([[0,2], [1,2]]) )
# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

print( get_root([[0,1], [1,2], [2,0]]) )
# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)
```