# Parsing a pandas dataframe into a nested list object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion

Does anyone have a neat way of packing a dataframe including some columns which indicate hierarchy into a nested array?

Say I have the following data frame:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame(
    {
        "var1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 9],
        "var2": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        "group_1": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
        "group_2": [None, 1, 2, 1, None],
        "group_3": [None, None, None, 1, None],
    }
)
```

```
   var1  var2  group_1  group_2  group_3
0     1     5        1      NaN      NaN
1     2     6        1      1.0      NaN
2     3     7        1      2.0      NaN
3     4     8        1      1.0      1.0
4     9     9        2      NaN      NaN
```

The `group_` columns show that the records on the 2nd and 3rd rows are children of the one on the first row. The 4th row is a child of the 2nd row, and the last row of the table has no children. I am looking to derive something like the following:

```py
[
    {
        "var1": 1,
        "var2": 5,
        "children": [
            {
                "var1": 2,
                "var2": 6,
                "children": [{"var1": 4, "var2": 8, "children": []}],
            },
            {"var1": 3, "var2": 7, "children": []},
        ],
    },
    {"var1": 9, "var2": 9, "children": []},
]
```

Comment: This might help: [How to convert a list of edges to a tree in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71478182/how-to-convert-a-list-of-edges-to-a-tree-in-python)

Comment: You say *"The 4th row is a child of the 2nd row"*, and indeed 48 is a child of 26 in your final tree structure, but the `'group_3'` field of the 4th row is 1, not 2. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Read it like this: the second row's group is `1.1`, whilst the 4th row's group is `1.1.1`, indicating that it is a sub-version of the 2nd row. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You could try if the following recursive `.groupby` over the `group_n` columns works for you:

```py
def nest_it(df, level=1):
    record = {"var1": None, "var2": None, "children": []}
    for key, gdf in df.groupby(f"group_{level}", dropna=False):
        if pd.isna(key):
            record["var1"], record["var2"] = map(int, gdf.iloc[0, 0:2])
        elif level == 3:
            var1, var2 = map(int, gdf.iloc[0, 0:2])
            record["children"].append({"var1": var1, "var2": var2, "children": []})
        else:
            record["children"].append(nest_it(gdf, level=level + 1))
    return record

result = nest_it(df)["children"]
```

While going over the key, group tuples from a (nested) `df.groupby("group_n")` 3 things could happen:

- The key is a `NaN`, i.e. it's time to record the `var`s and there aren't any more children.
- The level is 3, i.e. the end of the dataframe is reached, so it's also time to wrap up, but this time as child.
- Otherwise (recursion): Put the recursively retrieved children in the resp. list.
- Remark: I've only initialized the `record` dicts front up to get the item order as in your expected output.

Result for the sample:

```py
[{'var1': 1,
  'var2': 5,
  'children': [{'var1': 2,
                'var2': 6,
                'children': [{'var1': 4, 'var2': 8, 'children': []}]},
               {'var1': 3, 'var2': 7, 'children': []}]},
 {'var1': 9, 'var2': 9, 'children': []}]
```